# What's wrong my mips code?

Tags: assembly, mips

I'm a student and studying mips.. I wrote it to simulate at qtspim, but it doesn't work.
QtSpim said instruction references undefined symbol at la   $s0, $arr  but I don't know why.
Can you fix my mips code?
++
Thankyou. I fixed $arr into $ arr.
But when I simulate it, it doesn't seen anything on console.
Do you know why?

```
.text

.globl main

main: 

      addi $sp, $sp, -4
      sw   $ra, 0($sp)

      la   $s0, arr         --- was la $0, $arr
      addi $s1, $zero, 5
      add  $a0, $zero, $s0

      li $v0, 4     
      la $a1, msg1     
      syscall

      move $t0, $zero

L1 : sll $t1, $t0, 2       
     add $t2, $a0, $t1

     li $v0, 5
     syscall
     move $t2,$v0

.data

msg1 : .asciiz "input 5 numbers" 
arr  : .word 0,0,0,0,0
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You've had your question answered. If you have further questions, please post them as new, separate questions. Don't edit this one to add more. Before you post your next question, consider adding some comments about what the code is supposed to do, and what the system-call codes are. Also double-check where the system calls expect to find their arguments.

Answer (score 3):

`arr` is a variable, not a register, so you should remove the `$`. That is, write:

```
la   $s0, arr
```

instead of

```
la   $s0, $arr
```